# How to programmatically extract the "top of the roof" for a straight skeleton structure?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, polygons

I'm referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton) Straight Skeleton. For example, after generate a straight skeleton structure for a strictly simple polygon such as below, my goal is to extract the red line. At first, I figure it would be simply not including the edges which contain vertex lie on the polygon contour, but I soon realised with cases such as the second figure, even with doing so, I would still have some "branches" left that is not filtered out.

Any suggestion?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess the first step would be to define exactly what "top of the roof" means.  In other words, how do you do it manually:  What is your rule?  I think having a clear definition of this would suggest possible algorithms.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you should measure the distance from each of the skeleton vertices to the closest point on the contour, and treat this as a height. You can identify top of roof segments by having higher endpoints than others. But the exact criterion is going to depend on your definition, as ad2004 says.